# Non-force using 'Jedi'

Tags: star-wars

Were there ever any people to follow the Jedi Path that were unable to use the force? Of course, I know that to truly be a Jedi, one had to be able to use the force. Were there ever any folks who decided to follow the Jedi way of thought, just without the force?

Comment: Sure there were. Who do you think was in all of those temples, maintaining their records, cleaning their buildings, maintaining their weapons. Those are all people who believed in the Jedi path but were unable to utilize the Force. They could not earn the title of JEDI, but they served as they could.

Comment: So, like the Mr. Filch of the Jedi temple...

Comment: If by Jedi's Path you consider dueling with a lightsaber that would be quite possible that many people were able to... For example, Greivous: `You fool! I've been trained in your Jedi arts by Count Dooku...`

Answer (score 8):

You didn't really define "Jedi Path", so it's hard to answer. But as far as it can be answered, "no".

Jedi path was **all about** the Force and Jedi's connection to it. Everything else (morality, ethics) was secondary.

Were there people who wanted to do good deeds and meditated and chose not to anger and experience other negative emotions and helped others? DUH. Of course. Were they "following Jedi Path"? Not in any way, shape or form.

Case in point: [Prince Isolder](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Isolder). Luke senses that he has latent Force abilities, but very weak, and counsels him on Jedi Path. But it's all around the Force first, and morality second. The ONLY reason he spent so much time/effort on Isolder was the Force connection, even if weak; and not the fact that Isolder needed moral counseling as a human.

There were some members of the Jedi Order that were not very strong in the force, but I don't think that answers your question. (NJO had a Jedi whose name escapes me who was basically an order historian and not very strong as a Jedi.)

Your question is like asking if anyone followed Christian path without believing that Jesus Christ existed or died for their sins. The former would make them possibly good, moral or whatever person - but in no way shape or form a Christian.

Comment: "Everything else (morality, ethics) was secondary." Um...that sounds like the **Sith** path. I don't disagree that the Force was 100% essential, but it sounds like you are saying any increase in connection (power) in the Force justifies any means.

Answer (score 5):

**No.**

The semi-canon "[The Jedi Path: A Manual for Students of the Force](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Jedi_Path:_A_Manual_for_Students_of_the_Force)" (based on the 6 official Star Wars films and the Clone Wars TV series and created in direct collaboration with Lucasfilm) defines someone who follow the Jedi Path as someone who strives to observe the three primary precepts of Jedi teaching;

- **Mastery of The Force**
- **Knowledge of the wider world**
- **The attainment of self-discipline.**

While someone could theoretically focus the latter two, the ability to gain mastery of even the most basic elements of the Force (healing, absorbing energy, mindfulness of the living force, telekenesis) is solely the purview of those who are [Force Sensitive](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Force-sensitive).

[image]